# How to debug matlab code without gui

Tags: matlab, command-line

I have recently started using MATLAB without GUI by starting matlab with -nodesktop option and it is considerably faster.

However presently I have no way to debug a .m script in non gui mode. I have to open the default matlab editor every time I have to debug.Has anyone figured out a way to do it?
Thanks in advance

I am using Ubuntu Linux, in case that helps.

Comment: Side note: `matlab -nodesktop -nojvm` is even faster!

Comment: -nojvm does not allow me to plot graphs.

Comment: ah I see. Yeah it has its limitations. Good for running quick-and-dirty code.

Comment: Maybe consider an editor which has an matlab mode - like emacs or vim. It might be easier to set breakpoints from there and step through.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To set breakpoints with the command line, [`dbstop`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) is the tool (plus [`dbclear`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbclear.html) to clear breakpoints and [`dbstatus`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstatus.html) to list them).

There are presently 17 different forms to `dbstop`, which allow you to specify various combinations of:

1. The M-file in which to stop
2. Line number
3. Sub-function
4. Conditional to an arbitrary expression.  For example,

   ```
   dbstop in myFun.m at 224 if ~exist('x','var')
   ```
5. At any run-time error (`dbstop if error`)
6. At a specific error (e.g `dbstop if error myFun.m:barErrorId`)
7. At any warning (`dbstop if warning`) or specific warning
8. If `NaN` or `Inf` are encountered (`dbstop if naninf`)

See the documentation for `dbstop` for details and good examples.

Also get used to [`dbcont`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbcont.html) (or F5), `dbstep` (or F10), `dbquit` (Shift+F5), `dbstep` (also `dbstep in`, `dbstep out`), [`dbstack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html) (to see where you are and how you got there). The keyboard shortcuts may be different outside of Windows.

Far less used, but still very useful are `dbup` and `dbdown`, which allow you to switch workspace context (memory stacks).

See the summary of functions and a list of examples and how-to pages in the [MathWorks page on Debugging](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html).

---

Related to the "`db`" functions is [`checkcode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/checkcode.html), which will check your code for possible problems before you even run it. This is a nice substitute for the red squiggly underlines that you would get in the MATLAB Editor.

Once you get a hang of `dbstop` and it's syntax, you won't often need to insert a [`keyboard`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/keyboard.html) into your code, but it's always an option.

Answer (score 7):

Try placing the `keyboard` command in your code to insert a breakpoint. When the `keyboard` command is reached, MATLAB will drop into an interactive prompt that you can use to inspect variables. For example:

```
x = rand(10,10);
y = rand(10,5);
z = x * y;
keyboard; % you can interactively inspect x, y, z here
z = sort(z);
```

To leave keyboard mode, you can type `dbquit` to exit the program, or `return` to continue executing the program.

Another trick is to turn on `dbstop if error` which will automatically drop you into an interactive prompt whenever your code crashes.

Comment: That was what I was looking for. Are there any more tricks like interactively enabling and disabling a breakpoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MATLAB -Dgdb` if that helps. This sets gdb as the debugger. You will need to be familiar with gdb of course.

Once you do that, use the [standard gdb commands](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html%60) to debug it.

**EDIT**

My mistake. Above won't work for M-Files. (Not having MATLAB to try things out is a pain :)

MATLAB has a pretty good set of [debugging commands](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/debugging-code.html) you can use from the commandline. If you insert keyboard commands in your MATLAB code, you can then use the commands.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean here. Using that will allow me to debug matlab as an executable , but not a .m script itself. Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: My mistake. I uninstalled MATLAB from my system a while ago, so couldn't validate my own answer. Let me edit my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use MATLAB's editor debug button to debug within MATLAB environment